# Python 3.6.5 won't install pygame or LiveWires for Windows 10 (pip doesn't work either)

Tags: windows, pip, pygame, installation, livewires

I have Python 3.6.5 for class and need to install pygame and LiveWires.  I have Windows 10 and I cannot for the life of me get them to install.  I am on day 4 trying everything I can and everything I find.  I cannot get them.

I read that Python doesn't install pip for Windows 10 so I tried getting that too but I got no where.  Please help me.  I am going bonkers.

I am new to Python so please be clear.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? What errors do you get? What output does `python -m pip install pygame livewires` produce?

Answer (score 0):

`livewires` seems to be abandoned. The code was not updated in 4 years. I see `import Tkinter`, so I think the code is Python2-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you command line.
`python3 pip install pygame --user`
Hope this could help!